# set.Visibility(View.GONE) not making the Button and EditText gone, and it's showing up like I didn't even add the code

Tags: java, android, xml

Trying to make two login, one for admin, one for user. They share the same layout, but admin has additional TextFields and Buttons to add data to the menu. So when logging in with user credentials, the TextFields and Buttons will be `setVisibility(View.GONE)`, but it's not working at all, in fact it's showing up like `setVisibility(View.GONE)` was added at all. Any advice would be appreciated.

**loginpage.java**

```
DatabaseHelper myDB;
EditText LoginEMail;
EditText LoginPassword;
Button LoginBtn;

LinearLayout linearLayout;
View add_image;
View add_name;
View add_desc;
View add_data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loginpage);
    LoginEMail = findViewById(R.id.LoginEMail);
    LoginPassword = findViewById(R.id.LoginPassword);
    LoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.LoginBtn);
    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    add_image = new View(this);
    add_name = new View(this);
    add_desc = new View(this);
    add_data = new View(this);
}

public void Login(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(loginpage.this, MenuSelection.class);
    if (LoginEMail.getText().toString().equals("admin") && (LoginPassword.getText().toString().equals("admin"))) {
        startActivity(intent);
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
        else if(LoginEMail.getText().toString().equals("user") &&  (LoginPassword.getText().toString().equals("user"))) {
            startActivity(intent);
            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            add_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            add_name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            add_desc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            add_data.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
            else
        Toast.makeText(loginpage.this, "Incorrect E-mail or Password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**loginpage.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/LoginEMail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="E-Mail"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.204" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/LoginPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.338" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/LoginBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Log In"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.602"
    android:onClick="Login"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**menu_selection.xml**

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/menu_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/add_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@color/black" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/add_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/add_desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Description" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add" />
</LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Where are your fields inside xml file? I cannot read any LoginEMail or LoginPassword

Comment: @Dynoz I have added loginpage.xml in the edit, I didn't think I needed to show it.

Comment: You are setting visibility on 4 base `View` objects that haven't been added to the layout.

Comment: @codebod the 4 'View' objects are within the **LinearLayout** in the _menu_selection.xml_ , is it not? If it's not, then how do you add it.

Comment: There are `View`s in your XML file, but they are not associated with the variables you have declared in Java. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `add_image = new View(this);` you need to associate the variable `add_image` to the view in your XML layout using the `findViewById(R.id.add_image)` method. Similarly for the other 3 views that you have initialized this way.

You also need to delete the line `linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);`. The previous line setting this variable is correct.

Comment: Ok, so I've replaced all 4 of the Views, 'add_image = new View(this);' with 'add_image = findViewById(R.id.add_image)', but now it crashes on click.

Comment: Please, post log

Comment: So, I just saw the edit and deleted 'LinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this)', but it still crashes. Here's the log : 'Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.doonfood.loginpage.Login(loginpage.java:46)'

Comment: I can't see any reference to `menu_selection.xml` in your `loginpage` activity. Where is the association? The null pointer exception is caused by the app not being able to find `linearLayout` in the view hierarchy. What is the motivation for having two separate layout files here?

Comment: You can't change view visibility for views that aren't in the current view hierarchy. You need to move the relevant code to your MenuSelection class.

Comment: Add extras to `intent` to tell `MenuSelection` how it should display itself.